Bottom Navigation Bar is not showing
I am creating flutter application and there is an issue that I have created Bottom Navigation Bar and its not showing on screen
I have fully check it. there is no issue of Images(icons) path and neither any error or issue with yaml file. Everything is ok.
If anyone can tell the issue with experience please guide me.
It was showing a two days ago but now its not showing. I tried many ways but still its not working.
I have uploaded source code on Github. github.com/cogniqube/full_app
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:full_app/pages/Profile%20Page.dart';
import 'package:full_app/pages/home.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('assets/svg/home.png', height: 24, width: 24,), label:'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('assets/svg/heart.png', height: 24, width: 24,), label:'fav'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('assets/svg/add.png', height: 24, width: 24,), label:'add'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('assets/svg/speech-bubble.png', height: 24, width: 24,), label:'message'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset('assets/svg/person.png', height: 24, width: 24,), label:'profile'),

        ],
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  final pages = [
    HomePage(),
    Center(child: Text('Favorite'),),
    Center(child: Text('Add Post'),),
    Center(child: Text('Message'),),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];
}



Could you provide us with the source code that you are calling this widget?

Yeh sure! I have uploaded source code on Github.
https://github.com/cogniqube/full_app

Your "login" button is routing to "/home" building the HomePage widget, which doesn't have a BottomNavigationBar. If you instead route to "/main" to build the MainPage widget which has the BottomNavigationBar, you'll see it rendered.
On line 86 on your LoginPage widget, make the following change to the ElevatedButton widget:
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // ! You are already pushing the named route below so you can delete this first navigation
                    // Navigator.of(context).push(
                    //   MaterialPageRoute(
                    //     builder: (context) {
                    //       return HomePage();
                    //     },
                    //   ),
                    // );

                    // ! This named route has been changed to /main to return the MainPage widget which has the BottomNavigationBar
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/main');
                  }


Great! Problem Solved.
But I want Bottom Nav bar at every page. Is it work?

To get the Bottom Nav Bar at every page, you need to have every different page inside the scaffold that has the NavBar. This means you should have the different pages be different widgets that you change inside the "body" property of the scaffold, for example by using a PageView widget - note that this is a usual way of handling the navigation of the bottom nav bar buttons as well, where the buttons on the bottom nav bar change the index of the PageView.
Routes should then only be used to change to other pages that doesn't contain the bottom nav bar, like the login page.

Ok I understand Thank you!

In the logo page just change
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');

to
this should be the main page to start your app in
and then your route to other pages via Bottom Navigation Bar
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/main');

